# C# Reflection - SetValue by path to property

Tags: c#, reflection, propertyinfo

I'd like to update value in any public property by specifying a dots delimited path to it.

**But whenever I call my method I receive an error in line:**

```
pi.SetValue(instance, value1, null);
```

**Error message:**

*Object does not match target type.*

**My method:**

```
private void SetPathValue(object instance, string path, object value)
{
    string[] pp = path.Split('.');
    Type t = instance.GetType();
    for (int i = 0; i < pp.Length; i++)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty(pp[i]);
        if (pi == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Properties path is not correct");
        }
        else
        {
            instance = pi.GetValue(instance, null);
            t = pi.PropertyType;
            if (i == pp.Length - 1)//last
            {
               // Type targetType = IsNullableType(pi.PropertyType) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) : pi.PropertyType;
                var value1 = Convert.ChangeType(value, instance.GetType());
                pi.SetValue(instance, value1, null);//ERROR
            }
        }
    }
}

private static bool IsNullableType(Type type)
{
    return type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>));
}
```

Comment: why do you think `t.GetProperty` works on the type of your original object when you have a nested property? So when `instance` is of type `MyType` and has a property `MyProperty` of type `PropType`, `t` will allways evaluate to `MyType`, and `t.GetProperty(pp[1])` returns null, as `pp[1]` is a proerty within `PropType`, not within `MyType`. You need a recursive method which evaluates only the curent level.

Comment: @HimBromBeere He is updating `t` as he rolls through the loop, it isn't always the original value.  I still agree that recursive evaluation is a more appropriate solution though.

Comment: Btw.: what do you want to do wihen any intermediate property is not set (null)?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Aaah, indeed I missed that point within OPs code.

Comment: I think this will end up trying to set the value "one level too deep".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your original version will end up setting the value "one level too deep".

I think a recursive pattern would be easier to follow, and require less code.  Here is a quick version that I threw together that works on simple test cases.

There are several opportunities for optimizations (rebuilding the string on the recursive call), and edge cases (like `null` checks) that I don't have the time to handle right now, but I don't think they will be too hard to add.

```
public void SetProperty(object target, string property, object setTo)
{
    var parts = property.Split('.');
    var prop = target.GetType().GetProperty(parts[0]);
    if (parts.Length == 1)
    {
        // last property
        prop.SetValue(target, setTo, null);
    }
    else
    {
        // Not at the end, go recursive
        var value = prop.GetValue(target);
        SetProperty(value, string.Join(".", parts.Skip(1)), setTo);
    }
}
```

[Here](http://share.linqpad.net/uxxh2n.linq) is a LINQPad demo showing it in action:

```
void Main()
{
    var value = new A();
    Debug.WriteLine("Original value:");
    value.Dump();

    Debug.WriteLine("Changed value:");
    SetProperty(value, "B.C.D","changed!");
    value.Dump();
}

public void SetProperty(object target, string property, object setTo)
{...}

public class A
{
    public B B { get; set; } = new B();
}

public class B
{
    public C C { get; set; } = new C();
}

public class C
{
    public string D { get; set; } = "test";
}
```

It produces the following results:

[image]

Comment: I think, you have missed: Convert.ChangeType.  After adding the type conversion it works correctly. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm a little confused why you need to convert your value before setting it.  Unless you are trying to pass a `setTo` of a different type than the property value, it shouldn't be required.  In my example, the `D` property is a `string` and `setTo` is a `string`, no conversion needed.  The only way conversion would be needed is if you tried to pass something like a `string` in to a property that was an `int`, but that seems like a really odd thing to do.

Comment: I guess that would make sense if you were using this for something like handling a configuration file, where the values are *always* stored as strings and those values need to be pushed in to properties that you may not know the type of at the time you call `SetValue`.

Comment: Types will generally not match if the value will be entered by the user, e.g. in a text field. BTW, great work!

Comment: If that's the case, you should be aware that  you might have an issue with your conversion method. `Convert.ChangeType` sometimes has issues converting strings.  A more reliable method is to get a `TypeConverter` using `var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType);`, and then call `converter.ConvertFromString` to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I want to complete the answer [Bradley Uffner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779854/13166862)

```cs
public void SetProperty (object target, string property, object setTo)
{
  var parts = property.Split ('.');
  // if target object is List and target object no end target - 
  // we need cast to IList and get value by index
  if (target.GetType ().Namespace == "System.Collections.Generic"
      && parts.Length != 1)
    {
      var targetList = (IList) target;
      var value = targetList[int.Parse (parts.First ())];
      SetProperty (value, string.Join (".", parts.Skip (1)), setTo);
    }
  else
    {
      var prop = target.GetType ().GetProperty (parts[0]);
      if (parts.Length == 1)
    {
      // last property
      prop.SetValue (target, setTo, null);
    }
      else
    {
      // Not at the end, go recursive
      var value = prop.GetValue (target);
      SetProperty (value, string.Join (".", parts.Skip (1)), setTo);
    }
    }
}
```